# How filter in a grid view like '% value %'?

Tags: codefluent

how I can use a method search for generate a query like this SEARCH(name) select * from person where name like '% name %' and how I set this method to filter a gridview? I only see the option for startwith and endwith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CFQL` supports the concatenation operation, so you can use the following CFQL method:

```
SEARCH(Name) WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'
```

If you edit your model directly in XML, you have to escape the character `%`:

```
<cf:method name="SearchSample" body="SEARCH(Name) WHERE Name LIKE '%%' + @Name + '%%'" />
```

[Formal grammar](https://www.softfluent.com/documentation/CFQL%20Formal%20Grammar.html) of CodeFluent Query Language (CFQL)